# Mostrar resultado en una consulta MongoDB con Nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy tratando de mostrar el resultado de un count a una base de datos MongoDB con Nodejs, la estructura que devuelve el resutado es como una promesa de la misma, (NECESITO ES EL RESULTADO DEL COUNT POR EJEMPLO total = 5) , este es el codigo que estoy realizando:

**Funcion que realiza la consulta MongoDB:**

```
export const findCountSalesByNotIntegrated = () => Sale.find({ integrated: false }).count();
```

**Llamada de la funcion:**

```
const total = findCountSalesByNotIntegrated();
```

**Resultado mostrado con console.dir(total);**

```
Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,
  mongooseCollection: NativeCollection {
.........
.........
.........
    },
    '$timestamps': { createdAt: 'createdAt', updatedAt: null },
    '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
    '$connectionPluginsApplied': true
  },
  op: 'count',
  options: {},
  _conditions: { integrated: false },
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection: NodeCollection {
    collection: NativeCollection {
      collection: [Collection],
      Promise: [Function],
      opts: [Object],
      name: 'sales',
      collectionName: 'sales',
      conn: [NativeConnection],
      queue: [],
      buffer: true,
      emitter: [EventEmitter]
    },
    collectionName: 'sales'
  },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  '$useProjection': true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que estás retornando el objeto que construye mongoose, no el resultado. Además mongoose tiene una propiedad para contar los documentos con [countDocuments()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments), con Mongo, no con Javascipt, en temas de performance es mucho más benéfico.  Hay dos caminos para resolver este problema.

Lo más útil es utilizar funciones de tipo [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

Tendrás que modificar un poco tu Instanciación del router de express.js para indicarle que tras alcanzar la ruta, la función que le sigue será de tipo `async`, así Javascript espera que haya un `await` dentro de esta función
Te dejo un ejemplo que se asemeja a lo que tu pudieras tener, yo lo tengo con Typescript, pero al final es lo mismo

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'
import { Sale } from '../models/sales.model'
import { Query } from 'mongoose'


const TestRoute = Router()


TestRoute.get( '/', async( req: Request, res: Response ) => {

    const test = ():Query<number> => Sale.countDocuments({ integrated: false }, 
    ( err:any, count:number ) => count )

    const count = await test()

    res.status( 200 ).json( { count } )
})

export default TestRoute
```

También podemos seguir utilizando la vieja escuela de [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) recordemos es un truco sencillo pero inquebrantable contra proceso asíncronos. Aquí juega un papel importante `resolve y reject` Las dos posibles salidas de la promesa. Te dejé la documentación para que revises como funciona. Yo malinterpreto que si ya usas Node.js y Mongo sabes de lo que hablo.

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'
import { Sale } from '../models/sales.model'


const TestRoute = Router()


TestRoute.get( '/', ( req: Request, res: Response ) => {

    const test = (): Promise<number> => new Promise( (resolve: any, reject: any) => {

        Sale.countDocuments({ integrated: false }, ( err:any, count:number ) => resolve( count ) )
    })

    test().then( (count: number) => {

        res.status( 200 ).json( { count } )
    })

})

export default TestRoute
```

Por último y no menos importante es crear tu lógica dentro del callback del modelo de mongoose, esta la dejo al último por que depende mucho de tus reglas de negocio, pero no estaría de más comentarla

```
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'
import { Sale } from '../models/sales.model'


const TestRoute = Router()


TestRoute.get( '/', ( req: Request, res: Response ) => {

        Sale.countDocuments({ integrated: false }, ( err:any, count:number ) => {
            // Aquí toda tu lógica si es que hubiese más
            res.status( 200 ).json( { count } )
        })
})

export default TestRoute
```

Recuerda que, este código es de ejemplo y se limita a tu pregunta, deberías adicionar manejo de errores y excepciones en cada uno de los casos y blindar tu API.